# AS3 Starling custom shader crash "Error #3600: No valid program set" when computer is locked or put to sleep

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework, stage3d

I'm working on a Flash game using Starling, and I have started coming across an issue where my render crashes immediately after I put my PC to sleep/lock it and then turn it back on. The error I'm getting is:

*Error #3600: No valid program set*

I was not able to find any advice online on how to prevent this/re-initialize everything appropriately. I'm assuming this is part of a wider issue with how Flash/Starling handles the computer being put to sleep/locked.

Things I have tried so far:

- Catching the error and re-uploading the shader programs.
- Setting Starling.handleLostContext to true

Has anyone come across this issue before? Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's not the engine per say that is at fault but the graphic card that locks up everything and forces the loss of context. Handling the error and restoring afterward is the only way to deal with it.

Comment: Yeah everything seems to be pointing to that so far. I was secretly hoping for some kind of easy built-in 'Starling.cacheEverythingInRAMAndSolveAllYourProblems = true' parameter. :D

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your game is losing the GPU context.

On context loss, all GPU data is lost.  You have to restore textures, vertex buffers, etc.  Starling handles some of it for you when you set `handleLostContext` to true, but you still have to handle the textures.

If you use the AssetManager, it will handle re-uploading textures for you, which is clearly the easiest way to go.  It automatically creates a `texture.root.onRestore` callback function which Starling calls after it re-creates the context, and it will attempt to re-load your textures from wherever you first loaded them from, whether from disk, an embedded asset, or a URL.

You can also manually define the function yourself, though that is more complicated and as the article mentions, some gotchas are involved.

More information: http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/context_loss